# IgniteOutputCacheProvider example, how to initialize this class?

Tags: c#, outputcache, ignite

I've just started using Apache Ignite for .NET. In particular I am trying to write an output cache for some web APIs using the following library:

Apache.Ignite.AspNet.IgniteOutputCacheProvider

Can anyone provide any example on how to Initialize this class?

This is the Initialize() function:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        var cache = ConfigUtil.InitializeCache<string, object>(config, GetType(), null);

        _expiryCacheHolder = new ExpiryCacheHolder<string, object>(cache);
    }
```

I would like to see an example on how to use this WITHOUT using any xml file.
I already have a running instance of Ignite, how can I pass it to this class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ignite instance is running within the same process, then just use `Ignition.GetIgnite()` method to acquire it.

If you mean that there are standalone server(s) running, then you still have to start an embedded client to connect to cluster using `Ignition.Start(..)`. XML is not required, you can create configuration programmatically: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/configuration#c-code

Comment: How can I initialize the IgniteOutputCacheProvider class? I don't understand how I can pass an existing instance to this.

Comment: `Ignition.GetIgnite()` is a static method that will give you a running instance, so in my understanding there is no need to pass it the provider. However, I don't have a lot of expertise in ASP, so can be missing something.